# Output awk to file and print at the same time

Tags: bash

I'm trying to output this to a file and print it at the same time, I've tried to use `> test.txt` behind "scan" but that didn't work, anyone have any suggestions?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | awk -F ':' '/ESSID:/ {print $2;}'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use tee for this.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | awk -F ':' '/ESSID:/ {print $2;}' | tee test.txt
```

Comment: `tee -a` for append (equivalent to Bash's `>>`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in awk itself. Replace `>>` by `>`, if you don't wish to append to the specified file every time you run the command.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan |  awk -F ':' -v tfile=test.txt '/ESSID:/ {print $2; print $2 >> tfile }'
```